# Big commonHelper or seperate smallHelper in angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular 6 project. And I want to create helpers. (Forexample messageHelper, stringHelper, domHelper, gridHelper .... ) But my problem is for every page i must add this code:

MyPage.ts (First way)

```
 constructor(private messageHelper: MessageHelper,
     private stringHelper: StringHelper,
     private domHelper: DomHelper,
     private gridHelper : GridHelper) { }
```

This code will go longer for every helper. And i must write in every page(component). I think that, I create commonHelper and I add all helper to commonHelper as Public.

common-helper.ts (second way)

```
constructor(public messageHelper: MessageHelper,
    public stringHelper: StringHelper,
    public domHelper: DomHelper,
    public gridHelper : GridHelper) { }
```

If i write commonHelper like this, i must only add commonHelper to page. And then I can call commonHelper.messageHelper.ShowMessage().

MyPage.ts (Second way)

```
constructor(private commonHelper: CommonHelper)
```

1. **Question 1)** What is the best way for this, first or second way? Or are there any other best solution for this?
2. **Question 2)** My project will be very big project. So I'm afraid performance problem. Because i will add every component to huge commonHelper. Is this a problem?

Comment: you could do one service that handle every time of Help stuff and just inject it into the component you need

Comment: But these helper will have maybe 500 method when project go bigger. And methods will be very independent from each other. Forexample 
some are relevant to the message, some of relevant to Grid. @JacopoSciampi

Comment: Well, you can just do one function that simply print a message, passing the message as an args. You can also have stored this messages in a json file, so you can even have 50k messages and still have a fluent app

Comment: Thanks @JacopoSciampi. Yes, this is very dynamic solution. But the management is very very difficult. Because every method take different type and number of variable. And also they can be generic. So handling of this is very very hard.

Comment: Second way. because The less dependency is better.

Comment: But in second way adding very big commonHelper @MohammadDaliri. So, you are adding a lot of depency in commonHelper.

Comment: Well, it's the same thing as implmenting a multi-lingual app. You have a bug json with all the traduction and then you call the name of the string, and the traduction service to the job. If you just need to post a custom message (ie. like an alert) that's a good way to do it. You have just one dependecy. You'll import the service into the main module and let the components do the injection. But if you can specify in detail why you need to have different helpers, we can may find better solutions for you. Said that, if a component needs all the Helpers, just use one service.

Comment: CommonHelper don't need to other service. I'm using commonHelper like container. So, I'm adding all helper(for example 30 irrelevant helper) to commonHelper. Then I'm calling methods easily without inject every helper. I'm only add common. But i don't know, is this true way. But in below answer, malbarmawi's solution (static class) maybe better from mine. What do you think?  @JacopoSciampi

Comment: Is kinda the same logic, but I mentioned a service just because of the json stuff. You can do it as Malbarmawi said, but personally I don't like to have a struct like that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again @JacopoSciampi

Comment: @HasanOzdemir Injecting more service into a component or service and using it to another component is better than injecting more service to all component. So the second way is better.

Comment: Ok. What do you think of malbarmawi's static method solution in below or my second way? Which one is better? @MohammadDaliri

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `MessageHelper` as an example static class (all methods are static ) and use it in the body of the component class rather than inject the class in the  constructor

```
export class MessageHelper {
  public static log() {}
}
```

compoenent.ts

```
import {MessageHelper} from './message-helper'

export class compoenent {

 public methodA(){
   MessageHelper.log();
 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @malbarmawi . In future of project, What is the advantage and disadvantage of non-static (like mine) and static (your solution) method?